# AWS Quest - First Clue

Tags: word, cipher

AWS are hosting a puzzle hunt: https://aws.amazon.com/awsquest/ - the first clue is here: https://twitter.com/jeffbarr/status/972382654682120192

> The only thing we have to Amazon Sphere is Sphere itself..
>   [image: Iupq etaf Euzsqd Btux]

I've got two guesses so far:

- The only thing we have to Amazon Sphere is Sphere itself - sounds a lot like the quote from [Franklin Roosevelt's inauguration speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_inauguration_of_Franklin_D._Roosevelt)
- The image seems like Caesar shift: "Wide shot Singer Phil"

Any ideas on where to go with that next?

Comment: The first letter in the image is a capital I.

Comment: @Bass Thanks - "Wide shot" makes much more sense

Comment: I am guessing it could be Phil Singer, CEO at Marathon Strategies. He worked with the Presidential campaign for Hillary Clinton.

Comment: @jaydm26 I spotted that too - although I was probably hoping for the name to be the other way around. If I was to put a connection together, Louis Howe was attached to Roosevelt's campaign? (this feels a bit away from the path to me)